# Exceptions in C++ problem

Tags: exception, c++-cli

I have this code:

```
try
{
    files = Directory::GetFiles(path);
}catch(int){ 
    MessageBox::Show("Error getting files.");
    return 0; 
}
```

But when I run it and the `GetFiles` crashes, it still reports unhandled exception. Why?

Comment: In the catch(...), use the correct corresponding exception type, instead of int.

Comment: What exactly are you throwing - an int? An int pointer? Something that isn't an int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your're catching only exceptions of type `int`.

Use `catch(...)` to catch any kind of exceptions.

Comment: I thought that all exceptions are convertible to int. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx), `GetFiles` can throw the following exceptions:

```
IOException     
UnauthorizedAccessException     
ArgumentException   
ArgumentNullException   
PathTooLongException    
DirectoryNotFoundException
```

You do not catch any of them. The only exception you catch is of type `int` which cannot be thrown by `GetFiles`. To resolve the problem, either add catch statements for each of the exceptions above and handle them appropriately or use the ellipsis to catch all exceptions:

```
try {
  files = Directory::GetFiles(path);
} catch(...)  {
  MessageBox::Show("Error getting files.");
  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe "Unhandled exception" is also used in Windows to mean memory protection error, and is not always the same thing as a C++ exception, which is what you're trying to catch here.

Possibly the path you're passing in has some garbage data in it. If the path is ok then you need to make sure you catch all the types of exceptions possibly thrown by your function, not just `int`.